# JSF HelloWorld The requested resource () is not available

Tags: jsp, jsf

I'm trying to make HellowWorld app with JSF. I make Dynamic web proj, choose JSF v 2.0 for configuration, then Disable library configuration. Then I add jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, jstl-api.jar and jstl-impl.jar to my lib folder. Then create simple jsp and when try to start it i get  `The requested resource () is not available.` I think it's something with the mapping of the Faces Servlet in web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `FacesServlet` is mapped in `web.xml` and that the request URL (which appears in browser address bar) matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet`.

E.g., if you have a `simple.jsp` file in webcontent and the `FacesServlet` is mapped on an `<url-pattern>` of `*.jsf`, then you need to open it by http://localhost:8080/contextname/simple.jsf.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: why would you ever prefer the legacy/discouraged JSP over its modern successor Facelets which is the standard view technology since JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is jsp file shouldn’t be present inside WEB-INF folder move it under web content.
This will solve your issue.